# Tablet drawing horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines on its own / pressure sensitivity issues

Tags: wacom, gimp, bamboo

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and my tablet makes horizontal, vertical, and diagonal lines, whenever I draw something. Here's an example:

[image]

I changed the tablet mode to "Screen", but this is what's causing the problem, if I disable it then I lose pressure sensitivity.

It works fine with my other computers, just not with my laptop. My other computers have jolicloud andzion running on them and Gimp works fine on those with my tablet.

Does anybody have any ideas about what I should do?

Comment: does it appear only on gimp? or in the whole screen, is it the same in the first installation?, you could give some screenshots

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UCJEh.png

Comment: in the top left corner i tried to write this is my expample using the tablet but i get scribbles along with what ever strokes i make with the tablet, but my tablet works fine on other linux cpus

Comment: so where is this "Ploting" lines you described before? you are using 11.** version I think,

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/diJzJ.png they are thunder blot like i made them red i tried to draw a circle in the center of the image but i get these extra scribble, thank you for your help by the way i appreciate it

Comment: Got it, those lines have crossed the upper panel, that means it is not a misbehaving drawing by the app, it's with your graphics, I'm not a geek with this x server, so the only answer is install Graphics driver by Additional Drivers utility, If you could try unity 2d, it may be Work fine, Have you just tried to export the artwork as a Image(Jpeg,png) then are they the same as in the screenshot?

Comment: @Prasad: I think he edited the Screenshot with this red color, and the bug caused to cross the "screenshotted" panel. ;-)

Comment: thanks guys does anyone know how i can get back into my account i associated my email with it but i doesnt let me login in so this is my new account thank you once again eerybody
oh and where can u get ebooks on ubuntu and linux

Comment: it still didnt work but i got past the command thing i will try to find a solution i think i may just part the drive and add another os

Comment: How to open the `Ubuntu Desktop Guide`: Focus the desktop, go to the panel (top left), click `Help` → `Ubuntu Help`. Alternatively open the Dash and type in Hel...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be what is described in this bug report: [Wacom Bamboo One tablet random coordinate malfunctions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/863154).

You can solve it by installing the Personal Package Archive **ppa:aapo-rantalainen/gimp26-noghostline**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aapo-rantalainen/gimp26-noghostline
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gimp
```

Alternatively you could install the *deb*-files directly after [downloading from the mentioned PPA](https://launchpad.net/~aapo-rantalainen/+archive/gimp26-noghostline/+build/3001278). You need to download and install

- gimp-2.6.11-2ubuntu4-1+oneiric
- gimp-data-2.6.11-2ubuntu4-1+oneiric
- libgimp2.0-2.6.11-2ubuntu4-1+oneiric

This worked for me.

Comment: Ohh no i misunderstood the whole question, I thought he got some graphics problem!.. Thanks anyway, without you, that guy should be dead :-)    I got a similar problem with my desktop, and it disappeared after the drivers !!!

Comment: also im extremely new to unbuntu i was using jolicloud before this os, can i get a link to a place where i can learn more about installing personal packages, lol, i'm sorry for all 100 of my newbie questions, but i appreciate the help

Comment: W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Open `Software Sources` (Windows key and type softw...) and uncheck *CDrom ...* - then your updates should run without these error messages. Be careful adding ppas, because they provide you with updates which are not from official ubuntu sources! In doubt you should prefer installing packages the second way I described. Just download them and then doubleclick, they get installed with Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: im still having problem with it, the other input devices are disabled aswell such as my mouse and stuff should i change those to screen mode aswell or leave them alone